# how to resize the button image in iphone

Tags: iphone

im new in iphone.now im developing button image view in iphone.here images are images displaying large size i want to resize the images. that means images are displayed like medium size. i implement code like this.

```
 images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bearlarge.jpg"]];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bufflo_large.jpg"]];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camel_large.jpg"]];
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];



 int row = 0;
 int column = 0;


 for(int i = 0; i < images.count; ++i) {



 // UIImage *thumb = [images objectAtIndex:i];

  UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];



   button.frame = CGRectMake(column*105+14, row*105+10, 50,50);


  [button setImage:[images objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  button.tag = i; 




  [view addSubview:button];

  if (column == 2) {
   column = 0;
   row++;
  } else {
   column++;
  }
   }
 //[view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, (row+1) * 80 + 10)];
    self.view = view;
 [view release];
```

can any one plz send me code for how to resize the button images in iphone.

Thank you in advançe.

Comment: please reformat your code ;) (The "{}" button when editing)

Comment: the images will get resized to fit within the button size, in the above code. What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create this category for UIImage:

```
- (UIImage *)rescaleImageToSize:(CGSize)size {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [self drawInRect:rect];  // scales image to rect
    UIImage *resImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better add a UIImageView over the button. So that you can easily change the frame size.

**CODE**

```
UIButton *imageBut=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
img.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
[imageBut addSubview:img];
[self.view addSubview:imageBut];
[imageBut release];
[img release];
```

Or else, use

```
[button setBackgroundImage:YourImage];
```

Comment: i need to display selected image as full image thats why i choose buttons

Answer (score 0):

setImage will set the image with original size in which you are included that into your project.

setBackgroundImage will resize the original image.

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[images objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)scaleImage:(id)sender 
{
      if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
      {
        lastScale = 1.0;
        return;
      }

  CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

      CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;

     CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

  [[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

   lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
```

}